# Is it proved there is no elementary closed formula for $f(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N n^q$ for rational $q$ unless $q$ is a non-negative integer?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So since $\sum_n 1/n^2$ has such a crazy limit sum, and other supportive reasons, it seems like there should be no elementary closed form formula for $f(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N n^q$ for some fixed rational $q$ unless $q$ is a non-negative integer. Is this true? If so, what is the easiest way to see it? If there are exceptions for some fixed $q \notin {\mathbb N_0}$, what are they and what is the formula?

Comment: Actually the formula for any $q$ is crazy hard. For positive integer $q$ the solution is a combination of polynomials. But the way to construct said polynomials is *not* closed-form. If you throw rational, irrational, and transcendental $q$ into the mix, it becomes apparent that a random value of q has a 0% percent chance of having a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, I will address $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$. The Riemann zeta function is defined as
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$
You are therefore evaluating $\zeta(2)$, which is [equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Next, I will discuss your formula
$$f(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N n^q$$
This formula can be expressed in terms of the generalized harmonic numbers (more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)). We say the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) of order n of m is given by
$$H_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^m}$$
As I understand, you are looking for an equation for $H_{N,-q}$. The [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) presented below does just that:
$$H_{N/a,-q}=\zeta(-q)-a^{-q}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{N+ak^{-q}}$$
where $\zeta(x)$ is the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) as was introduced above, and $N$ and $a$ are integers. Setting $a$ equal to $1$ will give you your equation.

Comment: The introduction of the Zeta function is elegant, and I appreciate relating new quantities to existing studied quantities such as Zeta. However the second part of your final sum formula, the infinite summation, to me looks just as mysterious as the original finite summation I gave in the question. I have not much more hope for a closed form formula for that infinite sum, than I originally had for my finite sum in my original post. Also it's a bit questionable to me whether Zeta is truly closed-form, but I guess I'm ok with assuming it is. Also what if $q \geq -1$ in your infinite sum?

Comment: I understand your concern with the infinite sum I gave you. There does exists another formula for the generalized harmonic numbers, but I hesitated to include it in my answer due to its complexity and restricted domain. The formula is as follows: $$H_{n,r}=n^{-r}+\frac{\psi_{r-1}(n)}{\Gamma(r)}+\zeta(r)$$ where $\psi_k(n)$ is the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html), $\Gamma(n)$ is the [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and $\zeta(x)$ is the zeta function. This only applies to to odd $r\geq 3$.

Comment: However, the function given above includes integrals and infinite sums and complicated functions, which is why i do not think it answers your question. These (this one and the one presented in the answer) are the only functions for generalized harmonic numbers that I have found... Now I will address the zeta function. The zeta function, or [Riemann zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) is one of the most studied functions in number theory as it has been [closely linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) to primes.

Comment: There exists plenty of relationships and identities linking it with many other functions, and I encourage you to look them up. They are some of the most interesting and beautiful mathematics out there. Here are a few links:
wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

wolfram - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Riemann hypothesis (linking primes and the zeta function) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers
Hope all this makes it clearer! I would be happy to clarify further if needed...

Comment: @user2566092 Couple final notes... I just realized the link I gave for the Riemann zeta function in my second comment is the wrong one and I cannot edit it for some reason, sorry... The actual link is given in the last comment
Also, I wanted to conclude by saying that the closed form you are looking for probably does not exists, but these types of functions have been very largely studied.